# Multiple punctuation stripping

Tags: python, regex, string, punctuation

I tried multiple solutions here, and although they strip some code, they dont seem to work on multiple punctuations ex. "[ or ',
This code:

```
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    for i in words:
        while regex.match(i):
            regex.sub('', i)
```

I got from:
 [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) was good but i still encounter problems with double punctuations.
I added `While` loop in hope to ittirate over each word to remove multiple punctuations but that does not seem to work it just gets stuck on the first item "[ and does not exit it

Am I just missing some obvious piece that I am just being oblivious too?

I solved the problem by adding a redundancy and double looping my lists, this takes extremely long time (well into the minutes) due to fairly large sets

I use Python 2.7

Comment: Can you add a sample string where `regex.sub('',???)` doesn't work?  (In other words, fill in `???`).

Comment: not sure what you are asking to be honest, sample string in place of i?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm asking for.  To me, it looks like the regex/sub you have should work ... a concrete example showing it fail would be helpful.

Comment: I added print i
above regex.sub('', i) and it leads to infinite [" had to Control C out of it. I tested punctuation set, both items are included. I am baffled

Comment: So the string it has trouble with is `["` -- because the re you're using has no problem turning `'["'` into `''`  (as for the infinite loop, check out the answer by @LukasGraf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because [`regex.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) needs the **beginning** of the string or **complete** string to match.

Also, you did not do anything with the return value of `regex.sub()`. `sub` doesn't work in place, but you need to assign its result to something.

`regex.search` returns a match if the pattern is found anywhere in the string and works as expected:

```
import re
import string

words = ['a.bc,,', 'cdd,gf.f.d,fe']

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
for i in words:
    while regex.search(i):
        i = regex.sub('', i)
    print i
```

**Edit**: As pointed out below by @senderle, the while clause isn't necessary and can be left out completely.

Comment: Oh, right. *Slaps forehead*. But -- in that case, is the `while` clause necessary at all? Why not just call `sub` directly?

Comment: @senderle Good point, you're absolutely right, the while clause is unnecessary.

Comment: Still doesnt work, I added if regex.search(i) where your print i is, it still enters that if statement, i dont even know how thats possible

Comment: @rodling Did you also read my comment about assigning the return value of `re.sub`? Notice the `i = ...` in my code.

Comment: @rodling, then you're additionally doing something wrong in another part of your code we don't get to see. The code I posted works, and if you replace `print i` in that snippet with `if regex.search(i): ...` it will _not_ step into that `if` statement. Can you reduce your problem to a test case that is executable and complete with some data, and demonstrate why it doesn't behave as it should?

Comment: @rodling Also, the code as I posted it of course does not change the list `words` (strings are passed by value, not reference). It writes the result of the substitution to `i` which gets overwritten every iteration. That's why I `print` it, I wanted to keep the difference to your code as minimal as possible.

Comment: @LukasGraf fixed it! i was writing the variables wrong
    regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    clean_words= []
    for i in words:
        if not regex.search(i):
            clean_words.append(i)
Used that because i dont need '' space in the list. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @rodling Glad you got it to work :) One last tip though: You don't need the whole `regex.search` business. Simply run `regex.sub` on all your words: `clean_words = [regex.sub('', w) for w in words]` - one line, not counting the regex itself.

Answer (score 2):

this will replace everything not alphanumeric ...

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",my_text)


>>> re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","","A [Black. Cat' On a Hot , tin roof!")
'A Black Cat On a Hot  tin roof'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
>>> print str.translate("My&& Dog's {{{%!@#%!@#$L&&&ove Sal*mon", None,'~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\|}{;:/><,.?\"\'')
>>> My Dogs Love Salmon
```

Using this str.translate function will eliminate the punctuation. I usually use this for eliminating numbers from DNA sequence reads.